# Move windows between Spaces in Mac OS X using only the keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-spaces

How can I change the active space while taking the active window with me?

In Gnome, I can press `Shift-Ctrl-Arrow` to move virtual desktops, bringing along the active window.

I'd love the functionality to be the same in Mac OS X using Spaces, any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, there's no keyboard-only shortcut (AFAIK).  However, if you click and hold the window you're trying to move and then use the keyboard shortcut you have assigned to the Space you want to move the window to (typically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> or whatever the Space number is), that will do what you're looking for (move the window to the chosen Space and make it the active one).

Source: [Move windows to Spaces via keyboard shortcut Desktop](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071027122153453)

Comment: Amazing that this is the best out of the box solution ...and still needs the mouse :D

Answer (score 3):

[SizeUp](https://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) offers this feature.

It's not possible without third party software, not even [Hyperspaces](https://hyperspacesapp.com) does it, surprisingly.

Comment: Sizeup did exactly what I want, but I have to warn others that it pops up an alert every few minutes of usage unless you buy the software.

Answer (score 0):

## Skhd

[skhd](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd) can do this and much much more if you install ChunkWM. It's free and open source. You can see how to set the hotkey to do exactly what you want in the example config file,

- https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd/blob/master/examples/skhdrc#L186

Code,

```
\# send window to desktop and follow focus
shift + cmd - x : chunkc tiling::window --send-to-desktop $(chunkc get _last_active_desktop); chunkc tiling::desktop --focus $(chunkc get _last_active_desktop)
shift + cmd - z : chunkc tiling::window --send-to-desktop prev; chunkc tiling::desktop --focus prev
shift + cmd - c : chunkc tiling::window --send-to-desktop next; chunkc tiling::desktop --focus next
shift + cmd - 1 : chunkc tiling::window --send-to-desktop 1; chunkc tiling::desktop --focus 1
shift + cmd - 2 : chunkc tiling::window --send-to-desktop 2; chunkc tiling::desktop --focus 2
shift + cmd - 3 : chunkc tiling::window --send-to-desktop 3; chunkc tiling::desktop --focus 3
shift + cmd - 4 : chunkc tiling::window --send-to-desktop 4; chunkc tiling::desktop --focus 4
shift + cmd - 5 : chunkc tiling::window --send-to-desktop 5; chunkc tiling::desktop --focus 5
shift + cmd - 6 : chunkc tiling::window --send-to-desktop 6; chunkc tiling::desktop --focus 6
# shift + cmd - 7 : chunkc tiling::window --send-to-desktop 7; chunkc tiling::desktop --focus 7
```